# Result of grep can't be stored in variable

Tags: shell-script, shell, grep, variable, output

I want to get a date from a file name. This works using this code:

```
for filename in OH/*
do
    echo $filename |grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{14}'
done;
```

Now i want to save the result to a variable like this:

```
for filename in OH/*
do
    result=$($filename |grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{14}')
    echo $result
done;
```

But i get 2 empty lines printed. What am i missing there?

Comment: Can you list the files to get filename exemple? Thanks.

Comment: An example would be: BLA_BLUB_BLURR_20180123231157.csv.gz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dropped the `echo`:

```
for filename in OH/*
do
    result=$(echo $filename | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{14}')
    echo "$result"
done;
```

or [better yet](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/86440),

```
for filename in OH/*
do
    result=$(printf %s "$filename" |grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{14}')
    echo "$result"
done;
```

or

```
for filename in OH/*
do
    result=$(grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{14}' <<<"$filename")
    echo "$result"
done;
```

Comment: `${filename:$((-21)):-7}` (in `bash`) would also pick out the date stamp, if the file name suffix is always the same length.

Comment: It isn't always the same length. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Kusalananda, `${filename: -21:-7}` is enough to disambiguate it from `${par:-}` (space between the `:` and `-`). And actually that's an arithmetic context anyway, so you could do even `${filename:0-3*7:-7}` without the `$(( ))`.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks! I was scratching my head over that, but not for long enough it seems :-)

Comment: Why not `grep -Eo $filename '[[:digit:]]{14}'`? Seems more portable than using `<<<` .

Comment: `rien333`, that would look for the pattern `$filename` (or rather, the pattern corresponding to the value of the `filename` shell variable) in a file named `[[:digit:]]{14}`...

Comment: There is a clear chance that some other files will match the glob `OH/*` but not the grep regex. In such case, a NULL result will be printed. Avoid with `[ "$result" ] && echo "$result"

Comment: Quoting `"$result"` seems reasonable. Edit done.

Comment: @isaac I’m not sure what quoting buys you here, at least with an empty result. Care to explain?

Comment: No, it is not related to the empty (NULL) comment. That is why it is a separate comment. It is related to "quoting your expansions" as a reasonable good coding practice. I assumed you know it, that's why I directly did the edit. Better now? :-)

Comment: @isaac right that makes sense, thanks for the edit. “Quoting `"$result"` seems reasonable” is the sort of thing I would write in the edit comment, not as a post comment ;-).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing and echo inside the Command execution expansion, but better to use printf:

```
result=$(echo "$filename" | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{14}')

result=$(printf '%s' "$filename" | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{14}')
```

Of course, there is the chance that result is NULL if the file does not match the grep regex, for that we need a test:

```
#!/bin/bash 
for filename in OH/*
do
    result=$(printf '%s' "$filename" | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{14}')
    [ "$result" ] && echo "$result"
done;
```